# Prove $K\cap L$ is a subspace of V, but $K\cup L$ is never a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-verification, vectors

assume K, L are proper subspaces. Prove $K\cap L$ is a subspace of V, but $K\cup L$ is never a subspace. 
Solution:

if $v_1,v_2\in K$, then $c_1v_1+c_2v_2 \ in K$ [because K is a subspace]

if $v_1,v_2\in L$, then $c_1v_1+c_2v_2 \ in L$ [because L is a subspace]

Hence, $c_1v_1+c_2v_2 \forall c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R} $ are common elements and thus belong to  $k \cap L $. 
showing $k \cap L$ is closed under multiplication is direct. 
Thus $K\cap L$ is a subspace.

assume $v_1 \in K, v_1 \notin L$ and $v_2 \in L , v_2 \notin K$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction $(v_1+v_2) \in K\cup L$. then its either in K or L. Assume its in K. since K is a subspace then its closed under addition. hence, since $v_1+v_2\in K$ and $v_1 \in K$, then $v_1+v_2-v_1=v_2\in K$ a contradiction!

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You seem to have a $U$ that should have been an $L$. Also, you need to assume that neither subspace is contained in the other for this argument to work.

Comment: The claim is slightly wrong: $\\;W\cup U\;$ **is** a subspace iff $\;W\subset U\;$ , or $\;U\subset W\;$ . This is why you *needed* to assume what you did in the middle of your proof.

Comment: Corrected the U, L typo.

Comment: yes, if I assumed one is contained in the other than the claim is false.

Comment: But more strongly than this, the converse also holds: the line  $v_1 \in K, v_1 \not\in L; v_2 \in L, v_2 \not \in K$ in the middle of your proof is possible only if $K \not\subset L$ and $L \not \subset K$.